# Seleccionar llaves únicas y agrupar sus valores en un diccionario (Python)

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo una lista que contiene listas que consiste en

```
birthlist = [['1994', '1', '1', '**6**', '*8096*'],
['1994', '1', '2', '**7**', '*7772*'],
['1994', '1', '3', '**1**', '*10142*']...]
```

Los que he puesto en negrita son los días de la semana (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) y se van repitiendo a lo largo de la lista. Lo que he puesto en cursiva son el numero de nacimientos cada día.

Lo que debo hacer es crear un diccionario dónde aparezcan como llaves 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 y para cada una, que aparezcan el numero total de nacimientos para cada día.

Es decir, algo así como agrupar "por llave" y que sume de cada una todos los nacimientos que hay en ese día.

He probado a hacer esto y creo que se acerca a lo que quiero:

```
birzdictionary = {}

for b in birthlist:
    day_of_week = b[3]
    births = b[4]
    if day_of_week not in birzdictionary:
        birzdictionary[day_of_week] = []
    birzdictionary[day_of_week].append(births)

print(birzdictionary)
```

Sin embargo me falta el sumar los nacimientos, porque el diccionario simplemente junta un resultado de births con el siguiente y aparece un diccionario enorme.

¿Cómo lograr un resultado como...:

> ```
> birzdictionary =
> {1:39203423, 2:34902349, 3:389248932, 4:20953234, 5:342857554, 6:01929219, 7:1209233}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de crear listas dentro del diccionario e ir añadiendo elementos a las listas, simplemente puedes crear el contador que necesitas. Empezaría valiendo cero, y le vas sumando cada nuevo dato. Así:

```
birzdictionary = {}

for b in birthlist:
    day_of_week = b[3]
    births = int(b[4])
    if day_of_week not in birzdictionary:
        birzdictionary[day_of_week] = 0
    birzdictionary[day_of_week] += births
```

El código se simplifica ligeramente si haces uso de `defaultdict()`, que es un tipo de diccionario con un valor por defecto, de modo que si intentas acceder a una clave que no está en el diccionario, te la crea automáticamente con su valor por defecto. En este caso:

```
from collections import defaultdict

birzdictionary = defaultdict(int)

for b in birthlist:
    day_of_week = b[3]
    births = int(b[4])
    birzdictionary[day_of_week] += births
```

Como ves, a `defaultdict()` lo que se le pasa es el tipo del que serán sus elementos. Cuando necesita crear un dato nuevo (porque la clave no existía) instanciará ese tipo (en este caso un `int`) y asignará en esa clave el valor devuelto por esa factoría. En el caso `int` se crea un cero.

Comment: hay un pequeño error, `births` es un `str`. 
hay que cambiar `births = int(b[4])`

Comment: @meegle84 Bien visto! Gracias. Actualizada respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Solución alternativa usando [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) y [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter
import operator

print(reduce(operator.add, [Counter({n[3]: int(n[4])}) for n in birth_list]))
```